# SSRS group by expression causing divide error

Tags: reporting-services, expression

The expression below which is in a group is causing a divide by zero error when the IncomeOfficer value is chosen, the other parameter.

Has anybody experienced this and know of a fix that can be put in place?

```
=choose(Parameters!set.Value,Fields!IncomeOfficer.Value,Fields!ManagementArea.Value,Fields!RentGroup.Value,Fields!Tenure.Value)
```

I also swapped the Value,Fields!IncomeOfficer.Value, with the Fields!ManagementArea.Value, and identified that the first value in the list is causing the error.

Comment: how about you use IIF condition in addition to it, check if your Fields!IncomeOfficer.Value has value or not and then perform your next step.

Comment: Just to clarify, whenever your SET parameter is **1**, you get an error regardless of which field it is? But when SET = 2 or more, each field works?

Comment: To expand on @HannoverFist's comment, `choose` uses a **1**-based index, not **0**-based, so the first value is index **1**. Are you trying to access the first value using an index of zero?

Comment: @HannoverFist Yes that is correct,

Comment: @Chris-Latta is there a fix for this?